# How select latest date before today in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select records that have latest date before today?
For example, I have multiple records with dates of two days ago (eg. 2017-07-10). then I have more records with other dates (eg. 2017-07-09, 2017-07-08...).

Now I want to select all the records with date 2017-07-10. I don't want other dates like 09, 08, 07. Only select latest date before today. How can I do that?

```
SELECT
    AR.ID, mR.Description, AR.ActualReading 
FROM 
    machines M 
    INNER JOIN machinemeterreadinglist mRM 
        ON mRM.MachineID = M.ID 
    INNER JOIN meterreadingdescription mR 
        ON mR.ID = mRM.MeterReadingID 
    INNER JOIN actualmeterreading AR 
        ON AR.MachineMeterReadingId = mRM.ID 
    INNER JOIN meterreadingrecords mRec 
        ON mRec.ActualMeterReadingID = AR.ID 
WHERE 
    M.ID = '4364616d-8cff-4507-9dae-be4be8aee1f5' 
    AND mRec.rDate < CURRENT_DATE() 
LIMIT 
    1 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably refactor your `WHERE` clause, and *not* put the LIMIT, because you want *all* the records for one specific date and not just one (I guess):

```
SELECT
    AR.ID, mR.Description, AR.ActualReading 
FROM 
    machines M 
    INNER JOIN machinemeterreadinglist mRM 
        ON mRM.MachineID = M.ID 
    INNER JOIN meterreadingdescription mR 
        ON mR.ID = mRM.MeterReadingID 
    INNER JOIN actualmeterreading AR 
        ON AR.MachineMeterReadingId = mRM.ID 
    INNER JOIN meterreadingrecords mRec 
        ON mRec.ActualMeterReadingID = AR.ID 
WHERE 
    M.ID = '4364616d-8cff-4507-9dae-be4be8aee1f5' 
    AND mRec.rDate =
    (
    SELECT
        -- latest date with available data before today
        MAX(mRed.rDate)
    FROM
        -- same joined tables as original query
        machines M 
        INNER JOIN machinemeterreadinglist mRM 
            ON mRM.MachineID = M.ID 
        INNER JOIN meterreadingdescription mR 
            ON mR.ID = mRM.MeterReadingID 
        INNER JOIN actualmeterreading AR 
            ON AR.MachineMeterReadingId = mRM.ID 
        INNER JOIN meterreadingrecords mRec 
            ON mRec.ActualMeterReadingID = AR.ID
    WHERE
         -- same condition as original query
         M.ID = '4364616d-8cff-4507-9dae-be4be8aee1f5' 
         AND mRec.rDate < CURRENT_DATE()      
    ) ;
```

You can check a simulation of your scenario at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=6bb9112686b1b57c544f614ef255fc07)*

---

*Side note*: Your five-table structure can probably be simplified, and the JOINs look strange to me. I've tried to reproduce your structure from the them.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can just compare to yesterday's date:

```
SELECT AR.ID, mR.Description, AR.ActualReading
FROM machines M INNER Join
     machinemeterreadinglist mRM
     ON mRM.MachineID = M.ID inner Join
     meterreadingdescription mR
     ON mR.ID = mRM.MeterReadingID inner Join
     actualmeterreading AR
     ON AR.MachineMeterReadingId = mRM.ID inner join
     meterreadingrecords mRec
     ON mRec.ActualMeterReadingID = AR.ID
where M.ID = '4364616d-8cff-4507-9dae-be4be8aee1f5' AND
       mRec.rDate = CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Comment: Using this I can only get data with yesterday's date. What if I don't have any record in the whole week but I need to get the latest available dates only from the records?

Comment: @batwing . . . Then you would have a different question -- and it should be asked as a new question.  This one is quite explicit:  "Now I want to select all the records with date 2017-07-10. I don't want other dates like 09, 08, 07. Only select latest date before today. "